# Batch Processing of for loop results

Tags: oracle, plsql

Have a look at the below query:

```
Begin
 For i in (query returning 10k records)
  loop
   statements;
  end loop;
End;
```

I want to process the query results in batches of 100. Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: `Explicit cursor` or `cursor for loops` might be used. However elaborate more so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cursor, or my below proposition in pseudo-sql code - merely to present that it can be done:

1) Create a temporary table that would divide your data into buckets using `ntile()` analytic function.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table AS (
  SELECT *, ntile(100) as bucket
  FROM table
)
```

2) Loop for every bucket and retrieve data to manipulate it

```
FOR i IN ( SELECT DISTINCT bucket FROM tmp_table )
LOOP
  -- get rows from tmp_table with WHERE bucket = i
END LOOP
```

This solution will not loop over every 100 rows, but it instead does partition your data to buckets depending on how many of them you want, so the row number per bucket depends on your total row count and **n** argument of `ntile(n)` function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd better wish to process them fast?

There are many ways to do it depends of processing details. Just for example, you can use explicit cursor with [BULK COLLECT LIMIT 100](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html) clause to process 100-records pieces of data.